# Does $ (A \lor B \lor C \implies P)\land (\neg A \land \neg B \land P \implies C)$ imply $P\implies A \lor B \lor C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, propositional-calculus

I am working on the following exercise from Dummit and Foote and I just want to make sure my logic is correct: Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Prove that $H \cup K$ is a subgroup iff $H\subseteq K$ or $K \subseteq H.$

I am attempting to prove that if $H\neq K$ and $H\subset K,$ then $K\subset H.$ By the logic given in the title, will this prove the forward implication of the exercise (I have already proven the converse)? I don't know anything about manipulating logical statements in the propositional calculus, so I wanted to make sure my intuition is correct.

Comment: In the titled question, the 2nd premise (alone) implies the conclusion.  To see this, set up a truth table for the 16 T/F possibilities of A, B, C, and P.  Then eliminate those possibilities (from the 16) that violate the 2nd premise.  The remaining ones will all *obey* the conclusion.  Hand waving, if P is true, then either A or B is true **or** the 2nd premise kicks in.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not seeing how that relates to what you are attempting to prove about subgroups

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the original question, we can first assume p.  Then deduce the right side of the longest conjunction.  Then apply the definition (x$\rightarrow$y) defined as ($\lnot$x $\lor$ y).  So we have ($\lnot$($\lnot$a$\land$$\lnot$b$\land$p) $\lor$c).  If we assume c, then ((a$\lor$b)$\lor$c).  If we assume ($\lnot$($\lnot$a$\land$$\lnot$b$\land$p)), then (a$\lor$b$\lor$$\lnot$p). If we assume $\lnot$p, then we have a contradiction, so ((a$\lor$b)$\lor$c) follows.  If we assume (a$\lor$b), then ((a$\lor$b)$\lor$c) follows. In either case, ((a$\lor$b)$\lor$c) follows.  In either case, ((a$\lor$b)$\lor$c) follows.

So, yes, your intuition is correct.